# PHP - разработчик должен ли знать html?

Tags: php, html, html5, frontend, backend

В большинстве публикаций о найме PHP разработчиков не указывают о необходимости знать html. Предполагается ли знание html php разработчиками по умолчанию? Если да, то на каком уровне?

Comment: Без `html` в вебе вообще ни куда

Comment: @Alpha а почему вы решили, что это про веб? Ничто не мешает писать api-бэкенд на php без единой строчки html, и его знание в общем-то необязательно

Comment: @andreymal HTML на каком-то уровне должен знать каждый разработчик. А желательно вообще каждый ;)

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica ну так-то да, знать должен вообще каждый человек, ведь html проходят в школах на уроках информатики :) (Впрочем, за абсолютно все школы не уверен, но в моей школе такое было)

Comment: Я думаю, если определенный вид деятельности конкретно на этом рабочем месте предполагает знание html - то они понадобятся, и их будут требовать. В отдельных случаях думаю не будут требовать. Но я думаю html должен знать каждый разработчик который имеет отношение к вебу.

Comment: Должен владеть в совершенстве

Comment: @Sergey зачем? В совершенстве должен знать фронтенд-разработчик, а php тут никаким боком

Comment: @andreymal На уроках информатики проходят еще и паскаль, но про паскаль не скажешь, что он вообще кому-то нужен ;)

Comment: @andreymal Фронтенд-разработчик в идеале должен знать в общих чертах бэкенд и наоборот.

Comment: Получить базовые знания по html - это пару часов просмотра youtube. Посмотреть и не мучать себя вопросом "надо/не надо".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Акроним PHP когда-то означал «Personal Home Page», сейчас это просто «PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor» — «PHP: препроцессор гипертекста». В подавляющем большинстве случаев, PHP используется для создания сайтов, ну а как можно делать сайты и не знать HTML хотя бы на базовом уровне, если вы на PHP все таки сайты делаете?

Так что наверное, если явно не указано иное, от PHP-разработчика, которого нанимают для участия в создании web-сайтов, все таки ждут базового знания HTML, так же как и базового понимания структуры HTTP-запросов/ответов, например.

Answer (score 0):

> PHP (/pi:.eɪtʃ.pi:/ англ. PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor — «PHP: препроцессор гипертекста»; первоначально Personal Home Page Tools[13] — «Инструменты для создания персональных **веб-страниц**») — скриптовый язык[14] общего назначения, интенсивно применяемый для разработки **веб-приложений**.

Исходя из определения, этот язык чаще всего используется при веб разработке. Если вы видите в публикации о работе, требование - HTML значит вероятнее всего вы будете касаться фронтэнда  или готовить контент для него, где вам придется учитывать особенности HTML

Если программист при найме на работе вообще не знает HTML и знает PHP это как минимум вызывает вопросы.

На каком уровне, стоит спросить у работодателя...